# How to package multiple internal swift modules (frameworks) in a single 3rd party framework?

Tags: ios, swift, module, frameworks, target

In our Xcode project we've started implementing ios modules as a way to divide our massive codebase into isolated sections.

We've got modules for such things as:

```
Common
Product1
Product2
Product
App
```

Where App uses Product1, Product2, and Common, and Product1 uses Common, but Common knows nothing about higher level items.

In XCode/Swift, these are implemented as separate Targets, and generate frameworks that are imported into the higher level targets.  It works great for the app.  And the end product app compiles without caring that it comes from multiple targets via dependency frameworks.

We also have an actual Framework that we deploy for 3rd parties.  Previously we we selected all the files that would exist in the framework and made them dual members of the framework target and the app target.

Now however we have this kind of dependency, where lower level modules are included as "target dependencies" in xcode.

```
ProductFramework3rdParty
Product1
Common
```

The ProductFramework is compiling fine in simulator it can be embedded in a barebones sample app and run as an embedded binary.  This is the goal.

On Device however, it is giving the error that it cannot find the Common framework at runtime.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Common.framework/Common
Referenced from: 
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/**/**/ProductFramework3rdParty/ProductFramework3rdParty
Reason: image not found
```

It only works if I embed the Common, and ultimately the Product1 modules in the 3rd party app also.  This is not really the intended goal, to have to delivery our official framework, as well as the internal modules to a client to include.  We may have 5-10 modules in our code ultimately, and would like to package it all into the single distributed framework.

How can we do this?

I tried, unsuccessfully, changing the Mach-O for Common from dynamic to static, and it created a long list of linking errors I couldn't get past.  As well as ballooning the Common to 100mb, much larger than previous.